# How to serve a static json from the node devserver (Nx)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nomachine-nx

I am developing a React app with Nx. For reason out of my control I need to serve a static JSON file under a fix dedicated url while testing and debugging, but also I cannot influence the host part, so the `fetch` call goes to `localhost:4200` (i.e. the devserver). In production, this would be avoided by a setup with nginx.

The serve target uses this executor:

```
"serve": { 
  "executor": "@nrwl/web:dev-server",
  "options": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Is there a way to configure the devserver to serve a static JSON file under a given fix url in addition to its regular job ?